# Converting a JSON object into an array and returning array item

Tags: php, arrays, json

I Want to convert the string into an array and return the rating value. I've been able to return it as a string so its nothing wrong with the first line of code.

JSON:

```
{
    "id": "23",
    "rating": "31"
}
```

Code:

```
$json = file_get_contents('http:*****='.$film->id.'') ;
    $array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
    echo $array[1] ;
```

Comment: Have you tried `echo $array['rating'];`? Use `print_r($array);` and you'll see that the key is `rating`, not `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Line 3 should be:

```
echo $array['rating'];
```